# How to connect to vpn from the another subnet with the same external IP

Tags: vpn, nat, mikrotik

I'm working in a building where you rent a room for the office work. We have our server in one of the rooms and other employees in other rooms.

The problem is that server needs its own network (don't ask why. Too much to explain) so we set up a VPN on the Mikrotik router (RouterOS 6.48.1). While connecting from home works perfectly, doing that from other rooms does not work.

I was searching a lot about firewall and NAT rules but I can't find anything that will help me. In the picture cut-out area is the external address. Let's say it's 2.2.2.2
[Traceroute image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXo1K.png)

So I want employees from other rooms to be able to connect to VPN from My room to 192.168.43.2 router so he/she will be able to connect to devices available there.
[Our network image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAMMW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using VPN for that in the first place, and not routing between the two routers? Maybe your issue can be solved by setting up two static routes between your routers.